# How I can get File object in Ionic 3 use Camera plugin?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I need send array of files by POST method. I use camera plugin and get only FILE_URI(path)  to img. When I use input field with type='file' I can correct response( file object)  and can send it to server by POST method. How I can get such response(file object) using camera plugin and send to server  selected imgs, without   fileTransfer, because it send only one IMG, but my server waiting for only array of file(IMG).

Comment: You'll need to show us some code for this one. Preferablly where you are queuing up this images for upload.

Comment: @ChargerIIC Here, I get img `this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
      this.product_image.push(imageData); //push to array (but it only path)` send to server
 `let  params = new FormData(); 
 for(let i = 0; i < info_update.images.length; i++){
      params.append("image[]",  info_update.images[i]);
    }
    })
return this.http.post(url, params, headers)`

Comment: @ChargerIIC Also I try next: http://joxi.ru/l2ZKlbph8pL9yA but I get only info about img